# How do I start my app when the phone starts on Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, startup

I tried using the sample code [in this tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20100203080019/http://anddev.org/launch_activity_on_system-emulator_startup-t428.html) but it seems outdated and it did not work. So what changes do I have to make and to what files to have my app start automatically when Android finishes booting up?

Answer (score 340):

First, you need the permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also, in your`AndroidManifest.xml`, define your service and listen for the **BOOT_COMPLETED** action:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
    android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you need to define the receiver that will get the **BOOT_COMPLETED** action and start your service.

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And now your service should be running when the phone starts up.

Comment: I did not require the permission to run it on my emulator. I did not use the exact code. I used Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and kept MyService as 'Activity' rather than a 'Service'. But I dont think that would make any difference.
Is the permission required to run it on an actual phone? I am sorry if i am asking a silly question, I am new to android programming.
Also can you please suggest me some tutorial where I can learn such basic things about android - like activities, content etc.

Comment: Activities: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Services: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

To start your application when the phone actually starts up, you'll need to register the service as shown above, and then in there you can use startActivity() to start your app.

It's not a good idea to put a screen in front of the user if they didn't ask for it, though.

Comment: Just wanted to add that it'd be better to use `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` instead of hard-coding the string in your Receiver.  Also, should use the new `Intent(context, MySystemService.class)` constructor when creating the Intent.

Comment: Is there a reason for checking for intent type if intent-filter is used?

Comment: For some reason im getting `Multiple markers at this line
 - BroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved to a type
 - The public type StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver must be defined in its 
  own file` on the `public class` line. Any ideas?

Comment: It is possible to do something similar in IOS?

Comment: What is MySystemService?

Comment: @sports I think it's just your main activity of your app

Comment: @agmezr Dude, we are android people, ask a question in SO aith an IOS tag :)

Comment: Making a note of a bug that drove me crazy for a bit:

After random(?) number of changes the BroadcastReceiver for intent BOOT_COMPLETED would stop working on the device. The only fix I found was to REFACTOR the class to something else.

Android Studio 1.0.2.

Answer (score 130):

This is how to make an **activity** start running after android device reboot:

Insert this code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, within the `<application>` element (**not** within the `<activity>` element):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" 
    android:name="yourpackage.yourActivityRunOnStartup"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Then create a new class `yourActivityRunOnStartup` (matching the `android:name` specified for the `<receiver>` element in the manifest):

```
package yourpackage;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class yourActivityRunOnStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Note:
The call `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` is important because the activity is launched from a context outside the activity. Without this, the activity will not start.

Also, the values `android:enabled`, `android:exported` and `android:permission` in the `<receiver>` tag do not seem mandatory. The app receives the event without these values. See the example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#boot).

Comment: I like this "shortcut" to avoid having to make a local service. Does that code belong into the class that extends `Application` ? Maybe within `onCreate()` ?

Comment: it looks like that paragraph of code should be within `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: This code should be in the activity namely "yourActivityrRunOnStartup" which extends BroadcastReceiver class and inside onReceive() method.

Comment: a more easy a direct way without having to register a new service

Comment: I tried to giv a 10 upvotes but could'nt. Sorry and Thank you.

Comment: This should be THE answer because it answers the original question "How to start an Application on startup?" specifically.

Comment: It works for me only if I put the receiver in <application></application>

Comment: This worked for me, but ONLY if if I had just "<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />" in the intent filter. If I used the other two it did not work.

Comment: The line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` should not be placed within **<application>** element, it should be added in the root element of manifest file which is **<manifest>**

Comment: you make things simple. Thank you

Answer (score 72):

Listen for the [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) and do what you need to from there.  There is a [code snippet](http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup) here.

**Update:**

Original link on answer is down, so based on the comments, here it is linked code, because no one would ever miss the code when the links are down.

In AndroidManifest.xml (application-part):

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

...

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  //MyActivity can be anything which you want to start on bootup...
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);  
        }

}
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20150520124552/http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup

Comment: Which file is this code placed:    public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

Comment: It works, thanks! (worked on android 4.0.4 API level 15). Yup.. it's 2017 and I still have to develop for Android 4.0.4.. :(

Comment: Does not work on Android 8.0! Works on Android 4.0 though.

Comment: i am using same code but its not working up to kitkat version, i want to start application when android tv start

Comment: Put the receiver code inside the <application></application> tags

Answer (score 9):

Additionally you can use an app like AutoStart if you dont want to modify the code, to launch an android application at startup: [AutoStart - No root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart)

Answer (score 7):

For Android 10 there is background restrictions.

For android 10 and all version of android follow this steps to start an app after a restart or turn on mobile

Add this two permission in Android Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Add this in your application tag

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add this class to start activity when boot up

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
 }}
```

We need Draw overlay permission for android 10

so add this in your first activity

```
 private fun requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            val intent = Intent(
                Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + this.packageName)
            )
            startActivityForResult(intent, 232)
        } else {
            //Permission Granted-System will work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: requesting permissions crashes app

Answer (score 2):

The Sean's solution didn't work for me initially (Android 4.2.2). I had to add a dummy activity to the same Android project and run the activity manually on the device at least once. Then the Sean's solution started to work and the BroadcastReceiver was notified after subsequent reboots.

Answer (score 2):

For flutter user, you can create a file named `MainActivityReceiver.kt` in package folder. eg. `android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/your_company/package`.

`MainActivityReceiver.kt`:

```kotlin
package com.your_company.package

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

class MainActivityReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
      val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
      context.startActivity(i)
    }
  }
}
```

Modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` file refer to the first answer.

Comment: Would be nicer if you added the `AndroidManifest.xml` instructions in the answer instead of mentioning another answer, IMO :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` instead of `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` to avoid slow downs during the boot process. But this is only `true` if the user has enabled the lock Screen - otherwise this intent is never broadcasted.

Reference blog -  [The Problem With Android’s ACTION_USER_PRESENT Intent](https://funwithdc.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/the-problem-with-androids-action_user_present-intent/)

Comment: So, in other words, it shouldn't be used

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

I would like to add one point in this question which I was facing for couple of days. I tried all the answers but those were not working for me. If you are using android version 5.1 please change these settings.

If you are using android version 5.1 then you have to dis-select (Restrict to launch) from app settings.

settings> app > your app > Restrict to launch (dis-select)

Comment: I don't think this was ever standard. I have never heard of "Restrict to launch". Never seen it on different Samsung, Asus, Sony... It doesn't make any sense to me. It says that the app only is allowed to start? What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

This was preventing my app please do this - it pops and user checks the box to give permission

```
  // To start app after boot
private void startSystemAlertWindowPermission(){
    try{
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(! Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "[startSystemAlertWindowPermission] requesting system alert window permission.");
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:"+getPackageName())));
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "[startSystemAlertWindowPermission] error:", e);
    }
}
```