# How to launch the application upon booting up the device?

Tags: android

Can anybody share the sample code to how to launch android application upon starting/booting up the device?

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will launch an application on start up. You need to listen for [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED).

```
in AndroidManifest.xml (application-part):

<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
[..]
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
[..]

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);  
        }

}
```