# Unlock Android device programmatically and load application on boot up

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**Objective**: Unlock Android device programmatically and load application on boot up

**API**: 10 & 18

**IDE**: Eclipse

**Test device**: Emulator

I understand this issue has been widely discussed on stackoverflow and elsewhere. But I am unable to get this to work. My first **question** is

- Can the Emulator be programmatially unlocked and an application be loaded on boot up?
- I also read that after API 13 some there were some changes and I am not sure if I am accounting for these changes

Assuming the answer is yes please find code excepts below.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest 
package="com.example.display">


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.display.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.display.myreceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.display;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Unlock
        // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()
        Window window = getWindow();

        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**myreceiver.java**

I am expecting this section of the code to get executed on boot up and start the application.

```
package com.example.display;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class myreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }

}
```

**Issue:** I have loaded the above code to the emulator and re-started the emulator. I was expecting the code application to unlock the emulator and load the application of boot up. It doesn't happen...

Not sure where to look for next...

Most of the code snippets are from on stackoverflow.

Some of the post that I have referenced are

1. [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)
2. [How to launch the application upon booting up the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654831/how-to-launch-the-application-upon-booting-up-the-device)
3. [Android - Wake Up and Unlock Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741612/android-wake-up-and-unlock-device)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post what trouble you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi here i added the unlock programmatically and launch our application using the below code.You need to add the unlock code in broadcast receiver.
Please try and let me. Thanks

```
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class myreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     // Unlock the screen
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
    wl.acquire();

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
    kl.disableKeyguard();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService(myIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: Android 4.1.2 version