# Android locked for time<?>

Tags: java, android

Is there any method to retrive time when device is locked? For example, user locked his device and had it locked for 59 minutes. Then my application checks the time and unlock it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a direct method. However, you should be able to listen to `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `OFF` broadcast events and calculate the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that Android will stop you take current time even if device is locked.

You can take current time as below:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

And then you can unlock the screen through below code:

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
    wl.acquire();

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
    kl.disableKeyguard();
```

You can also find couple of stack overflow discussions around unlocking like:

- [Android - Wake Up and Unlock Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741612/android-wake-up-and-unlock-device)
- [Android - detect phone unlock event, not screen on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on)
- [How to Lock/Unlock screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically)
- [Unlock Android device programmatically and load application on boot up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273305/unlock-android-device-programmatically-and-load-application-on-boot-up)

Comment: OP is asking for the elapsed time, not the current time.

Comment: That can be taken by the difference with the time device was locked. What @ramzixp is asking is how to retrieve time when device is locked.