# How can I restart my application after rebooting of device?

Tags: java, android

I have made Android application which uses one background service. It works good, but if user reboot his device that my application will be stopped. How can I fix it, i.e. how can I restart my application after rebooting of device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/798818

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in following way :

Register a receiver which will be initiated when boot_completed  and add the following permission in android :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and add following lines  in manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.test.check.MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

                 <service android:name=".MyService">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.test.check.MyService" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </service>
```

Now in the **onReceive() method of MyReceiver** start the service :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         Toast.makeText(arg0, "boot completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.test.check.MyService");
         arg0.startService(serviceIntent);


    }
}
```

And now in onCreate method of the service launch the app you want using its package name :

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name");
            startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

This will fulfill your requirement.