# Android: Existing Handlers after device reboot?

Tags: android, android-handler

I have a question on handlers and their existence when device is rebooted, Say i have executed 3 handlers with a delay of 3 hrs using `postDelayed()`, i just wanted to know if, for an instance the device was rebooted, do those threads still exist? or do i need to execute them again?. if so, how do i automatically execute handlers after device reboot?. I've read some threads that i need to start a receiver in turn to run a service but im really confused on how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

> i just wanted to know if, for an instance the device was rebooted, do those threads still exist?

No. They also will not exist for your three-hour duration, anyway, as Android is likely to have terminated your process first. Please use `AlarmManager` for periodic work like this.

> if so, how do i automatically execute handlers after device reboot?

You don't. You can use a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` to reschedule alarms in `AlarmManager`, though.

Comment: hmmm yes, my app is more like an alarm thing, but i wanted to schedule an alarm, say 3 hours from now, and i can't think of anything else but to use handlers to fire the alarm at exactly the right time. Do you know how to fire up the alarm without using the handlers? i mean firing the alarm accurately, like the user will choose / set the time when to fire the alarm?

Comment: "Do you know how to fire up the alarm without using the handlers?" -- use `AlarmManager`, as I wrote. "i mean firing the alarm accurately, like the user will choose / set the time when to fire the alarm?" -- use `AlarmManager`, as I wrote.

Comment: i've done scheduling an alarm and also tried stopping it, but how do i auto stop an alarm say after 3 repeats?..

Comment: @lemoncodes: Call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager` after your third repeat, to cancel an existing scheduled event.

Comment: the problem is how do i flag the repeats, how do i know or count the repeeats, setReapting() returns void, where do i count them?

Comment: @lemoncodes: In a file. Or a `SharedPreferences`. Or a database.

Answer (score 0):

The handlers are gone after reboot. If you want to have them set on Android boot, you can write a system app that [always launches on Android start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android).