# Android to lock the home button and back button in android

Tags: android, button

hey i want to make an Application which will start when the phone will start, which i am able to do so but  my problem is to disable the "Home Button" & "Back Button" on start up an it should only be enable when i click an button on my activity which will be the home screen on start up, please help me out..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make an `intent-filter` for `BOOT_COMPLETED`. You can get the tutorials from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android)

To disable HOME and BACK

Lets se...
If your app is running and visible to user then you can do that by using the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK    || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
    {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do nothing
    return;
}
```

But if your app is not running then it is not possible for you to do that how ever you can make your [custom launcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) in that wey you can decide weather to show the screen or not

OR

You can disable the home key [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898876/how-to-disable-the-home-key)