# how to lock main button

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for how to lock the home buttons so that the cell phone does not respond to any physical button, to prevent security in the app
I did not find a code that helps me with this other than the back button ... I also need the home button, lock, go back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android to lock the home button and back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282544/android-to-lock-the-home-button-and-back-button-in-android)

Comment: I don't see how this "prevents security"

Comment: In other words, running your app will remove functionality from my device? No way!

Comment: Try this. Might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20945431/13685592