# How to launch the application when the device booted up

Tags: android

Iam developing one android app, for that app, i need to  start the my application at device start up.Can any one tell me how to do it?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register a `BroadcastReceiver` and then listen for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` event in that receiver.

```
public class yourBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            selfIntent.setClass(ctxt,  DestActivty.class);
            selfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ctxt.startActivity(selfIntent);                         
        }
    }

}
```

You will need to modify your `AndroidManifest` file too and register this receiver in the `Application` node

```
<receiver android:name="yourBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And this too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But iam getting error message "the application has stopped unexpectedly"

Comment: can you show some code? the activity which you are trying to spawn, your manifest file, and your logcat.

Comment: My application is installed on external memory.Is that the problem with the external storage?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.videoex" android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
 <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
 android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /></intent-filter></receiver>    </application></manifest>

Comment: public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      /* do your stuff here, mostly just copy&paste from other places */
     Intent i = new Intent(context, DownloadActivity.class);  
           i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(i);  

    }
 }

Comment: looks like you have not used the `uses-permission` correctly. Remove this `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` from inside of `receiver` node and put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` outside `application` node (put it before application node starts). I hope you have mentioned your activities properly in the manifest file

Comment: Thanks Rajeev.The problem is Solved.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you should first add a permission for that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and then define a receiver in your manifest also,

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and then define the receiver in your code

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);  
    }
```

}

Comment: I really hope the OP doesn't want to start an activity on boot, that would be really annoying.

Comment: for your context doesnt startActivity() respond
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)
and OP actually allows this :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow steps such as

1) register a broadCast Receiver with action `"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"`

2) then in the onReceive method of receiver you can start your activity/service or take any action as par your requirement. Here you already be in your application.

**Dont forget to add respective permission in manifest file**

[Here is the same question/conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Broadcast Receiver having android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED as the intent-filter action, registered in the AndroidManifest then on the onReceive method, start your desired app component.