# Make an app start on phone startup?

Tags: android, android-activity

Anyone know how to start an activity and the browser on phone startup?
I need: the phone startup, my activity block back and home button and start the browser.

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: are you trying to start up an a WebView in your application?

Comment: `block back and home button` ? Just curious Why? You can start your app on booting up of your phone( that too user has to either start the app manually once after installing or has to restart the phone once.)

Answer (score 0):

This question shows you how to start an app on phone boot up: [Launch apps on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android)

You can start the phones web browser with this code:

```
    String url = "http://www.example.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

You could instead use a WebView which means the user would not have to leave your application to see content.

You can block the back button press by simply catching it within your activity using onBackPress() and having it do nothing.

And while you can override the home button in a similar way to the back button this is not recommended, as you will be removing the users ability to pause/exit your application.