# How can I autorun Android Chrome homescreen app on startup

Tags: android, google-chrome, boot, homescreen

After adding a certain website to homescreen through Chrome for Android, I'm looking for a way to autorun that homescreen app as the device boots up. I found a few apps in the Google Play store that offer that behaviour but they don't list Chrome homescreen apps as possible to autorun on boot.

Any solution, anyone?

Comment: I purchased [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) + [AutoShortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut&hl=en) from the Play Store in hope that it would get the job done, but unfortunately, no dice. See the discussion [here](https://plus.google.com/117876353004095345287/posts/gP5ddhdDwuA).

Comment: It seems duplicate questions. please see on following link:                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android

Comment: @Kanti the question you are referring to solves a different problem, i.e. how to set an app to load on boot assuming that this is your own app and you have access to the src. This question refers to the launching of a Chrome homescreen app shortcut.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103192/start-chrome-as-web-app-on-android-start

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no solution right now. Chrome homescreen apps work slightly differently from regular apps. Please read here for the full details: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen

Specifically, Google developers have mentioned that Android can not detect Chrome homescreen apps as installed.

> Do not prompt the user to add your app to the homescreen. There is no
>   way to detect if the app is running installed or not.

So by extension, you are not able to run them at startup.

Comment: Is there some tool which can launch chrome in full screen?

Comment: @Сухой27 Read this: http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-force-Google-Chrome-to-fullscreen-in-Android
Also if this answer helped you, please upvote it thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Running homescreen apps on device boot up might be tricky since Android cannot detect them as installed, but here is a workaround you might be interested in:

- Install [AutoStart - No root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart&hl=en) on your Android device
- In the app, Set "Auto startup" to ON
- Add Chrome to the Applications list
- In Chrome, add the page you wish to launch as the browser start page
- *Optional* - Install a secondary browser and repeat the steps above in order to avoid interfering with the start screen of your regular browser
- *Optional* - Install an app like Fulscrn Free or similar and add your browser to the list of apps that run in full screen mode.

This way, every time you boot up the device, a browser will launch with the page you designate, almost as if it is launching the homescreen app.

Comment: Chrome tabs and url bar are still visible, unlike with homescreen app.

Comment: Even with a full screen all like Fulscrn Free?

Comment: Using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tsorn.FullScreen&hl=en as fulscrn isn't compatible with my device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

- Installed [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) . They are paid though.
- In Tasker, add a profile for "On device boot" and an action from Plugins->AutoInput.
- Follow the instructions in AutoInput to create an action that simulates a press on the web app's icon on the homescreen.
- I placed my icon on the default home screen, otherwise you might need to add a swipe action first to get to the proper screen.