# Android system application

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an android application.

When installing the application, I do not want that the application logo added in the "Applications" menu neither in the "Home". I want that my application run as a daemon and configurable from the "settings" and could stop/start it from the "settings" too

Is it possible to do that with Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only by making your own custom ROM mod, containing your own custom build of Android. SDK applications cannot modify the Settings app. Also, your app's daemon will never run, because nothing exists on the device that would start it.

Comment: According to this link, I think there is a way to start my application in the boot  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android

Comment: @MOHAMED: Oh, you can register for that broadcast. You will not get it until something uses an explicit `Intent` to invoke one of your components, on Android 3.1 and higher. Usually, that "something" is the user tapping on a home screen launcher icon. You do not want to have such an icon, and therefore there is nothing on the Android device that will ever use an explicit `Intent` for your app and, therefore, your receiver will never be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, judging based on "icon" being called "logo" etc I bet you got not much experience with the platform, but yes, you can have app not listed but that's usually implies certain other limitations as well. So "choose right tool for the task" case here. If you want to run in fully "stealath" mode you need to be system app which means you need to have own ROM as well as no external app can be system app on most devices (rooted is the exception but that's other story)