# What have I done wrong to make my app run at startup?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am just trying to make my webview app run upon the bootup of an android device. I already followed every single step mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android) however it does not run on device boot up. What am I missing here?

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Start Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,
                    MainActivity.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(serviceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Start Up not possible!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    //Note: To detect when a URL has started and finished loading, use WebViewClient.onPageStarted and WebViewClient.onPageFinished.
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

and here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aa.webview1" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</manifest>
```

Comment: what if you move uses-permission on top your <application> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your receiver is out of your application element, it should rather be inside

```
 <receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver"> // i am suppose to be a child of the application
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
 </application> // clossing application element
```

for more info check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) , [and here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)