# Start Android application at boot time without latency

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, receiver

I want to launch my application after boot completed. I followed steps in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android). Now, the application starts after boot completed **but** it takes 1-2 seconds. It means I see default launcher screen for 1-2 seconds.

I don't want to see default launcher application. The my application must be run as soon as boot completed.

Could you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: not possible....BOOT_COMPLETED is the first thing You can receive. Some less devices have QUICK_BOOT, but only a view.

Comment: you can make a launcher app but it cannot replace the default launcher unless the user willingly sets it as default launcher

Comment: Thanks.  You are right @TomTsagk , but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @sukru there are some things are not possible on android to protect users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way i can think of making this work is writing your own launcher.

more information:
[How to make a launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher)