# Get an App to start on startup

Tags: android, autostart

I have written a C# app.  It was written for the Windows OS that is installed on the USB PC stick.

This 'stick' has Windows 8.1 32 bit installed on it.

As Windows 10 is now released I am concerned that this OS will become obsolete.

If I upgrade to Windows 10, as I understand it I cannot control the windows update and any subsequent reboots.

My app is responsible for sending a stream of images from my IP camera to my Server which in turn renders these images to a browser for my clients.

An alternative route I am considering is using the Android USB stick instead.

I was going to purchase Xmarian and convert my C# code to these bindings.

But, can I get an app to auto-start on these Android devices?

The make is: 
MK809 III RK3188 Android 4.2 2GB RAM 8GB ROM Quad Core A9 Mini PC TV Box Stick C

any pointers, suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Xmarian will not convert a windows app to android. consider learning android

Comment: @haseeb I can use Xamarian to write an app for Android using C#. I have written some code on Java for Android many years ago but I prefer to have just 1 code base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in android you can use broadcast receiver to receive [BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android) event to get an application start when boot completed. and using broadcast receiver you can know many system events and events by other apps

Comment: thanks for your answer. I need to research this and see if I can get this to work with the device I am using but this device - because it is a Mini PC TV Box Stick already has a boot up so need to make this works. +1 for you answer and i will be back to accept if it works out OK. thanks :)