# how to load app directly without launching homescreen

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-package-managers, android-framework

When android device power on, is it possible to load one specific application without launching home screen?

How to make this change?

Where to change code

Setting permission as boot_completed works but before my application is loaded, the homescreen is shown for 5 seconds. How to disable android from showing any homescreen launcher before my application

Comment: I think it is possible using broadcast.

Comment: Can you give me more information. I am very newbie in android apps

Answer (score 2):

This mode is called kiosk mode, and android has provision for running devices in Kiosk mode, you can refer to [this guide](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) for the complete set up. Basically what you do is set up your app to listen to the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast and disable all actions such as back button home button minimize buttons etc. Also don't forget to set up an exit mechanism. Just follow the [guide](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) and you should be fine.

Comment: It works. But before application is loaded,  the homescreen is shown for 5 seconds. How to disable android from showing any homescreen launcher before my application

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And add Intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And then Now you can start your application's first activity from onReceive method of Receiver class:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android
```

For more information you can check this url [How to start/ launch application at boot time Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android)

Comment: It works. But before application is loaded, the homescreen is shown for 5 seconds. How to disable android from showing any homescreen launcher before my application

Answer (score 0):

if your device has been rooted, uninstall system applications on your device, but be careful that every app can not be uninstalled. install "Root-Uninstaller-Pro-8.3" app and do this. you must uninstall important system apps one by one and any time restart your device to see result until Achieve goal. if you uninstall an app that make your device Messed up, you should flash your device to restore apps and retry uninstallations. by this uninstallations, your boot time become too short and that 5 second will be disappear. good luck!