# automatically run an application on Android phone startup

Tags: android, startup

I want to start my application when phone startup

I just follow tutorial from [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/) but it doesn't work in my device.  Please see my method:

```
public class MyStartUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent ii = new Intent();
        ii.setAction("com.sat.servicetrack");
        context.startService(ii);
    }


}
```

and this is my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ServiceTrack"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<receiver android:name=".MyStartupReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.sat.servicetrack" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
</application>
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: what about running the same code on simulator ?

Comment: how can i know it's work in emulator or not?? @moujib

Comment: add a log on your onReceive method ...

Comment: Close the emulator and start again.

Comment: can you please show whole code of AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Start an Application on Startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similiar, but I was starting activity. Here is how I done it:

In Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

In Java code:

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(
                context,MainActivity.class),
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 20000, i);
    }
}
```

Your code seems to be correct, but try using PendingIntent ;) Hope it helps you

Comment: i have try put your code, i restart my device..but my service still not running..how it's??sorry for bother you :)

Comment: i have got error like this `05-16 15:24:21.766: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sat.servicetrack.MyStartupReciever in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sat.servicetrack-1.apk]
` what it is?? @Veljko

Comment: try to start some dummy activity, which starts your service. instead of running service immediatly.

Comment: i have got error like this 05-16 15:24:21.766: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(292): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sat.servicetrack.MyStartupReciever in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sat.servicetrack-1.apk] what it is?? @Veljko

Comment: have you just copied my code? mine receiver is called BootUpReceiver and yours MyStartUpReciever. Check that...you have made some typo for sure.

Answer (score 2):

try like this....

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(context, BootingActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

in manifest file...

```
 <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the Service.

Code like this.

```
Intent objIntent= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(objIntent);
```

Click [Here](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/start-service-from-broadcast-receiver.html) to know how to start service from broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, BootService.class));
        }
    }
```

and next you should implements BootService class extended Service