# Is it possible to run my Android app immediately after the OS reboots?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [automatically run an application on Android phone startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613538/automatically-run-an-application-on-android-phone-startup)

I have developed an Android app (not for phone). Is it possible to run my app immediately after the OS reboots?

Comment: What do you mean `not for phone`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613538/automatically-run-an-application-on-android-phone-startup

Comment: android can work for many cases not only for phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can have a BroadcastReceiver declared in your manifest to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and then respond to that in your BroadcastReceiver and do what you like.

```
<receiver android:name="MyBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```