# Location tracking Exception thread id=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4170ed58)

Tags: android, exception, location, tracking

I am new to android and I am developing an app that takes location for every minute and send it to server.This code works fine in my tab but it get closed when i install this in my redmi phone. Both have same version. My app get closed when it execute the location change method. I have mentioned my code for location change and error log below.

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    sharedpreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences
            (MyPREFERENCES,getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    uid=sharedpreferences.getString("uid",null);
    u_name=sharedpreferences.getString("u_name",null);
    Log.e(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"uid" + uid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    lati = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    longi = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
    String lat = Double.toString(lati);
    String lon = Double.toString(longi);
    //Toast.makeText(this,"user_id" + uid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Toast.makeText(this,"user_name" + u_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "latitude = " + lati, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "longitude = " + longi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try{
        new Save_asyncTask().execute(lat,lon,uid);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error thrown when calling Asyn Task", e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Async error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is my error log

```
08-12 15:50:52.147    3248-3248/com.example.netaxis_41.dial4meat W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4170ed58)08-12 15:50:52.157    3248-3248/com.example.netaxis_41.dial4meat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.netaxis_41.dial4meat, PID: 3248
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.example.netaxis_41.dial4meat.LocationNdSend.onLocationChanged(LocationNdSend.java:162)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Log.e(TAG, "Error thrown when calling Asyn Task", e); this id the 162nd line. I restore my mobile and my app start working fine. thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Is there any option in android to make my app run automatically when I switch on my mobile.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613538

Comment: Good reference thank you....