# Is it possible to have a Phonegap app start up automatically when an android tablet powers on?

Tags: android, cordova

We're giving android tablets to several clients to showcase some apps we've built, and we want to create another app to automatically start up as soon as the device is powered on (and perhaps only the first time it's powered on) to convey with some graphics and text that we have these other apps installed they should check out. Can I do this with PhoneGap or do I have to create a Java-based android app? Thanks very much.

Comment: not sure if you can do it with phonegap. But either way it would be difficult to do only the first time it powered on. Is more of an all or nothing kind of a thing I think

Comment: Are you creating your PhoneGap app via PhoneGap Build? Or do you have the Android SDK and such and are building your APK locally?

Comment: @Tim - actually, the one time part is simply a matter of setting a shared preference to indicate that you have already run.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But the broadcast receiver is still going to get a callback every time. Even if it chooses not to start an Activity the application is still technically running. I suppose that is a bit nit picky though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to do, a good example of what is required is posted in this thread
[How to Start an Application on Startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/1854553). The Java code would have to make its way as a [custom phonegap plug-in](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android) as you're using phonegap..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using [the Autostart plugin](https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart) (also compatible with PhoneGap Build).