# how to make Android Application restart automatically on phone restart

Tags: android

how to make Android Application restart automatically on phone restart.
i made an app for android and now i want that it will restart automatically when phone is restarted 
,can anyone please help me over this.?

Comment: You can check out the question and answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: can you please explain it a litte more that where to use this boot reciever in .java file

Comment: create 
BootReceiver.java file 

this file run automatic when BOOT_COMPLETED. and in this file you can right restart code

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.anddev.org/launch_activity_on_system-emulator_startup-t428.html

In manifest

```
  <receiver class=".MyStartupIntentReceiver">

            <intent-filter>

                 <action android:value="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                 <category android:value="android.intent.category.HOME" />

            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

MyStartupIntentReceiver-Class:

```
public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends IntentReceiver {



        @Override

        public void onReceiveIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {

                /* Create intent which will finally start the Main-Activity. */

                Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, LaunchOnStartup.class);

                /* Set the Launch-Flag to the Intent. */

                myStarterIntent.setLaunchFlags(Intent.NEW_TASK_LAUNCH);

                /* Send the Intent to the OS. */

                context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);

        }

}
```