# Set repeating alarm once a month

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am using alarm manager along with broadcastReceiver. I am able to set an alarm and all that. But I am stuck with how to approach my problem. I need to be able to set a repeating alarm and the trick here is to have it repeat every 14th of a month at 4:00 pm (so monthly alarm).

How do I go about it? I know how to make it repeating every day or every week as it is easy to calculate the how many milli seconds in a week, but when we are talking monthly, every month has different number of days so I can't set it with a fixed interval.

Any help here?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the req. you provided above, I would only schedule one alarm at a time, just calculate the new time values when the previous one is triggered.  One thing you will want to do as well is setup a service to listen for boot complete event.  Alarms do not persist through restarts.  you can find information on how to do that here [How to start an Application on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)