# My app background process stops, if device booted

Tags: android, notifications

my apps background process stops on device rebooting. What to do to make it always running also after device booted. Because my notification did not show on device boot

Comment: user broadcast receiver to listen boot complete event & start your app on boot complete

Comment: If you're not using `BroadcastReceiver` Then, simply use that. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/940096)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use BroadcastReceiver. and call your process inside this class. And in your manifest,

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadCastClass">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And add uses permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code for manipulate your application `onBoot` of your application -

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.d("OnBootReceiver", "Hi, Mom!");
   }
}
```

Add the below permission for `onBoot` service -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And, in your manifest file, you've to add the `OnBootReceiver` class for register it like below -

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

A perfect example from [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) available on [GitHub](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot)