# Best way for starting application on startup?

Tags: android, android-service, startup

I need to start my application on startup. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/1584654) where a service is started on startup. I also found [this thread](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=428) where they use an `intent-filter` in order to receive the `android.content.Intent.BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION` broadcasted on start up.

If I don't need to start a service, what is the best way for obtaining startup events of device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the receiver using `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` also add permission `"android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"`

in the onRecieve function start your luncher actiivity

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, First.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
```