# "One App" Android System

Tags: java, android, operating-system, rom

I created an Android app which communicates via USART with a µC in order to evaluate data. My co-workers and customers should use the tablet for only this purpose now. Is there any possibility to "hide" the Android OS or making it inaccessible?

Devices are rooted and I am willing to build custom ROMs (even though I do not have any experience with that yet). Are there any approaches available that I do not have to start from scratch?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. That what I'm trying to do !

The first thing I tried was to start the app just after the boot of the device (Quite easy [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)).

Then, I get Android source code, and I hide the bottom bar using [this code](https://github.com/ppareit/HideBar/)

The problem is, if your application is not stable ... you'll have some problem.

If you want to modify Android source code, [the developper doc](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) contains a very good tutorial to start !

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I can write another Service which permanent checks if the app is still alive. If not it restarts the app automatically.

Edit: And what about the hard keys. I'm sure that I can catch the back-button, but can one do that with the Home button, too?