# Best way to register a BroadcastReceiver on Android?

Tags: android

in Manifest or directly in Java code?
I tried to register an ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED in the manifest and it does not work, then I found that this receiver only can be registered in Java code, so which is the best way to register receivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receivers that are registered in the manifest will create a separate process if the app is not running to make sure broadcasts are received. Receivers registered in an activity or service are tied to the Activity/Service lifecycle, and you need to make sure to unregister them as well. Whether to use one or the other is based on the question whether the app needs to receive a broadcast every time it occurs, or only when the app runs.

Answer (score 0):

You should see this post:
[How to start an Application on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

add to manifest this:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

define the service in the manifest like this:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now make a new class with this:

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourMainActivity);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since Honeycomb, BroadCastReceivers that are registered in the manifest will not trigger unless the application is **run** at least once. This is to protect against malware, so that a user must explicitly give permission for an app. Obviuously if you register it in the code, then there is no such problem, as the app will have run.