# Android - app always be in background and unclosable

Tags: java, android, background-process

hi all i want to make my app be always in background i google a lot but i can't find anything good !
im also want to autostart my app when the device is BOOTED !
please someone help me with a resource code !

Comment: To be always in background, use background services. To auto start at boot, make a broadcast receiver which could listen to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.

Comment: you didn't searched enough. there are examples in te web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Start an Application on Startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this [Tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=428)

You need to create a simple `IntentReceiver` that will receive the

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Also go through this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup) as well.