# Prevent an ios app from clossing

Tags: ios, ipad, localization, gps

I am currently developing an ios app for a localization company. The company provides ipads to all his employees so this new app that i'm developing can keep track of them (in case of an emergency and to know if they are really working).

I already finished the app and everything is working fine but now the problem is that anyone can close the app and "hide" his position from us.

It is possible to do something about this?

Also it is possible to start an app on boot. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/3307382) but on Ios.

Is there anyway to "lock" the app so it can't be closed and only sent to background?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried with the guided access but the employees also need to use other apps (like safari) to do their work. Not only mine. I tried this and effectively you can't close the app but also you can't access other app. Or am I doing it wrong? I want to allow my app to be in background but not close. Sorry if i did not explain myself well.

Answer (score 1):

Many duplicates of this...

Settings - General - Accessibility - Guided Access.

Turn it on and you can limit what the iPad can do.

You can also stop it from closing apps.

Comment: But the employees also need to use other apps (like safari) to do their work. Not only mine. I tried this and effectively you can't close the app but also you can't access other app. Or am I doing it wrong? I want to allow my app to be in background but not close. Sorry if i did not explain myself well.

Comment: @agmezr ah, that isn't what you asked. In fact you didn't mention that at all in the question. You asked "Is there anyway to "lock" the app so it can't be closed?" The answer is yes, guided access will stop an app from being closed. But for what you want, no. Without guided access there is no way to stop a user from exiting an app (as far as I know). You may be able to do something with enterprise distribution and managed devices though.