# How to install preinstall app into the /data/app at first boot in android

Tags: android, system, recovery

I am trying to install some apps into my android set after recovery the set and first boot.

I don't know how to judge the first boot action. are there some flag in the souce code ?

**How to install the app into the /data/app/? where can i add relative install codes in the android source code ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want your applications installed on first boot after recovery, you need to have them in the userdata image.

So first thing is to prepare a `userdata.img` file that has the apps you want to be installed on first boot in the correspondence of `/data/app/` which should be just `app/` in the userdata structure, as the `DATA` partition is mounted on `/data`

So the procedure should be:

1. restore your device to factory with recovery;
2. enter bootloader fastboot mode;
3. [wipe your data partition](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html#unlocking-the-bootloader);
4. program your custom `userdata.img`;
5. reboot, the device should automatically install the apks in your userdata image

Comment: How would you get these apps to run on first boot?

Comment: @TheGwa: that's [a separate question with a separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/813810)

Comment: I have found on the Android 4.4.2 devices that the app needs to be run once manually or using `monkey` for the broadcast  receivers to be "registered" after that the apps open on boot.