# What exactly is the difference between service and system service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to create an Android system service that generates some data at a set interval of time and returns that to my activity through a callback.
I kind of know how to that with a local service (at least, I have some examples). I thought that a system service works like a regular service but is simply started with the system.
But now I have some doubts. Here's an example of a system service  - http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService - it exposes some API to the activity, but how to communicate from service to the activity? There's no onBind, I don't know how to send Intent to it, how to get anything back really.

Comment: you cannot create a system service unless you create your own ROM

Comment: Yes, I know, already done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a service when the phone is booting perhaps you can listen for the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE event.

Check out this link [How to start an Application on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

Comment: Noted for later use, but I want to use and understand a system service here.