# How to run my application when i start the smart tv box without entering it's menu

Tags: android

How to configure the smart tv box to run my android application when i start it, without entering it's menu ?

I have searched for something but nothing that can guide me.

Comment: What have you searched for, online? Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Beyond that, talk to the manufacturer of the "smart tv box" and ask them.

Comment: @CommonsWare that was what i thinked at first but after i asked some questions the manufacturer is going to make they're part to open by default with the application