# cannot autostart app on boot - got BroadcastQueue: Reject to launch app

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I used a popular method to make my app autostart on boot described here: 
[How to start an Application on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

The issue is that app doesn't start with the following message in logcat:

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Reject to launch app .../10186 for broadcast: App Op 60
```

What am i doing wrong?

PS.
Android 5.0.2, phone Asus zenphone

Comment: found an answer - asus have embedded app called Autorun Manager. When i've launched it and checked its settings - revealed that my app is in the list and has state "OFF" (disabled). After i've enabled my app the autostart feature worked fine

Answer (score 8):

this problem is caused by "Auto-start Manager", I have same problem.

To solve, "Auto-start Manager" > Tab "Lastest Items" or "Downloaded" > Find your App > Change to Allow.

Sorry my poor english.

https://www.asus.com/zentalk/thread-27102-1-1.html

Comment: What if Auto-Start Manager is not installed?