# BOOT_COMPLETED delayed on Android 4.4?

Tags: android, startup, reboot, bootcompleted

I am coding a kiosk app that should open on reboot.

The startup of my app after reboot is delayed for 20 seconds. So the user sees the home screen for this time and then my app opens.
Is there a way to show my app directly after reboot?

I use a rather slow device and the approach from this solution:

[How to start an Application on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

Comment: For a Kiosk app I would also recommend to registering your app as launcher.

Answer (score 0):

two  many app listening BOOT_COMPLETED  broadcast。