# how to create service that run on startup and on the background

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create application that will start when the device is start and will run on the background until the device will be shutdown.

I know that there are a 'services' and 'IntentService' and how to deal with them.

But i can't understand witch of them will be fit my my needed.

The service that i want to create will run on the main thread with no UI ( like the 'service' ) and do some action but this will be long turn service and from what i know .. to use a long turn service it better to use 'IntentService'

So, please any help ... how to do it ?
And how i start my service at the startup ?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/768567

Comment: For long time `Service`, you should use `startForeground()` in the `Service`

Comment: @Shaishav :   but how i start my service at the startup

Comment: You listen for `BOOT_COMPLETE` intent which will fire your `BroadcastReceiver` and in your `receiver` you can call `startService()`

Comment: @arnoduebel - this will popup the service when some receiver signal

Comment: @Shaishav : still .. the service will be start when some broadcaseReceiver will be call

Comment: Right....however, the `receiver` will kill itself after launching the `Service` on boot. Note that booting up a device is an event and the system fires up an intent to let the apps know of this event. To capture these "events", `receivers` are the only components that can be launched in its response

Comment: @Shaishav : got it ... thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `IntentService` is the best option for this case:

- Requests can be handled one by one.
- `NotificationManager` can meet your requirements to notify user that something happened.

In this case, you just need to call `startService` to start the service, and override `onHandleIntent` method，and it will do background work for you.

#### `Service` should be used in following cases:

- Requests need to be handled multiple simultaneously. or
- Components(activity or fragment) need to interact with the service. For example, to call the service APIs, to listen service callbacks. This case you should create a Bound Service.

Since your service need to run on the main thread with no UI, so you should use `Service` and override `onStartCommand` to handle request.

Refer to [API Guides Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: As pointed out by @Shaishav,  A broadcast receiver also needs to be registered that listens for Boot_Completed which can fire up the service again.