# How To Run a specific Application on Android Devices

Tags: android, system

I just want to learn how can i run my application on Android devices? 
I mean,it has to run automatically on startup and nothing will be allowed except the application.
I just want to do something like this. (See the video) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09F3byGTdZs

Additional Explanation:
I created an application.I want to run this on my tablet pc and everything else will be disabled except my application.When i start my tablet,my application will run directly and it's not allowed to go home screen,task manager or anything.Only my application will run on system.For example i got an application like instagram.I want to turn my android device to instagram device.I hope you understand.So sorry for bad english.

Comment: please say more detailes!

Comment: I created an application.I want to run this on my tablet pc and everything else will be disabled except my application.When i start my tablet,my application will run directly and it's not allowed to go home screen,task manager or anything.Only my application will run on system.For example i got  an application like instagram.I want to turn my android device to instagram device.I hope you understand.So sorry for bad english. @hamidrezabstn

Comment: this guide would help you with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup @PBSDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this link for Kiosk Application 
http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

Comment: Thank you for answer.Is this method safe?

Comment: You have to make your application "Default", then only it can run without any interruption of other App, use below link :

[link](https://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/)

Comment: Yes it is safe as you can do this process without rooting your mobile or tablet.

Comment: Hi, can you raise the Arrow upward to my answer.
It will be of great help for others to find the answer of this Kiosk mode.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer.
I have already created the video app like that, so is this link helpful to you ?