# launch android app when android device is turn on or restart

Tags: android

i have android app and its working good , but now i need to open the app automatically when android device turned on i tried many solutions but its not working ,

any idea please ?

i tried like this but not working

```
public class Bootup extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Reboot completed! Starting your app!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(context, AutoStart.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362719/how-can-i-start-android-application-on-device-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the following post:

[How to start an Application on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

You might need a [Receive_boot_completed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission. There are two answers in the post which show how to start either an activity or a service on app start.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch on the mobile, an intent will be broadcasted. Its `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

If you receive that intent via a broadcasted receiver then it you can detect if the device is switched on.

**Broadcast Receiver:**

```
    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent aIntent) { 

            // ToDo: Whatever I need at immediately after bootstrap
            Toast.makeText(aContext, "This message phone is turned on!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("..BOOT_ACTION_NAME...", "This message phone is turned on!");


}}
```

**Manifest Declaration:**

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.example.testing_demo.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Place the manifest code inside the application tag.