# Call Recording on Android 10 silent

Tags: android, call-recording

I have an example of Call Recording on this link: https://github.com/tntkhang/call-recording-master

It worked ok on android below 10, but when run it on Android 10 it got Silent. I tried many configurations but nothing work.

Anybody can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419653/cannot-start-activity-background-in-android-10-android-q/59421118#59421118

Comment: I tried to add that permission but the recording still silent.

Comment: Are you sure you have the permission? It is not enough to implement it just in the manifest