# Starting the app when a if statement is fulfilled

Tags: android, json, android-service

I wanna design an app that works in the background and fetches JSON data from an URL and if data was something specific app starts itself automatically.

I don't have any code because I searched around and found nothing.

is this even possible? and how should I proceed if yes?

Answer (score 0):

From android 10 you are not allowed to do that.
They introduced a background process limit which restricts activities and services to be started only if there is an already running instance in the background.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Also see this for further info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421118/6694770

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate your activity:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```