# How to launch app like Google's alarm app using alarm_manager in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, background, alarmmanager

I'm making alarm app using `android alarm manager` in flutter.

Alarm is correctly working by using [this hack](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30555#issuecomment-501597824).
But there is problem that some device doesn't launch my app when alarm is fired on background.

For example, When set the alarm and click home button, just `callback` function has been called, app hasn't been launch.

Using `Samsung s8`, app is launched when alarm is fired.
But emulator `sdk_gphone_x86_arm` and `Samsung s10` doesn't launch app.

I want to make google's alarm app, but some device doesn't launch app. what is problem?

Comment: You can launch your app from callback using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/intent

Comment: @DimaRostopira Thank you for comment! I've searched about `intent`, but I didn't know how to use this. So would you show me some example?

Comment: I think [android 10.0 version prevent to active intent service in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419653/cannot-start-activity-background-in-android-10-android-q).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find solution using few days!!

#### CAUSE:

Android 10.0(Q) prevent to start `Active` in background. You can see document [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

#### SOLUTION:

1. Add this in Manifest
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`
2. Allow permission at your flutter app
   (Route: `Setting` -> `Apps & notifications` -> Your flutter app -> `Advanced` -> `Display over other apps`)

#### REFERENCE:

[cannot start activity background in android 10, android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419653/cannot-start-activity-background-in-android-10-android-q)

Comment: Can you post a complete example?

Comment: @Bassel Alkhateeb I use [flutter-permission-handler](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler), but there is not system alert window permission. So I forked [repo](https://github.com/jja08111/flutter-permission-handler) from [this PR](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/pull/389).

Comment: @MaNDOOoo hi, can you please post an example of how you have achieved launching your app from the background using android alarm manager plugin? I'm really struggling to achieve this.

Comment: @Chris I achieved this by using the `BroadcastReceiver` of the `android_alarm_manager` plugin. Here is the [code](https://github.com/jja08111/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus/android/src/main/java/dev/fluttercommunity/plus/androidalarmmanager/AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java) that I used for my alarm app. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MaNDOOoo thanks for the reply. I don't suppose you'd be willing to share the code for your alarm app to demonstrate how you've implemented this?

Comment: @MaNDOOoo, nevermind! I just tried it on my device and it unlocked it :D Now I just need to bring the app to front/open it :D Thanks!

Comment: @MaNDOOoo actually, it would be really helpful if I could see what you've done because something isn't working right.

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately, I can't share my app code but here is a [greate alarm app example](https://github.com/geisterfurz007/random-alarm) that I referenced to make my alarm app. And here is an article that I wrote for guiding to make alarm app in Korean.

Comment: No problem, and thanks for your help. The only thing I'm having trouble with is getting the app to come to the foreground when the alarm triggers.

Comment: @Chris There are two points for launching the app to the foreground. First, [edit the `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` of the `android_alarm_plugin`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30555#issuecomment-501597824). Second, set the flags like [here](https://github.com/geisterfurz007/random-alarm/blob/master/android/app/src/main/kotlin/io/github/geisterfurz007/playground/MainActivity.kt) to show the app at the lock screen. (And here is [my article](https://jja08111.github.io/flutter/flutter-alarm-app/) that I missed linking to the previous comment.)