# Launch app from background events when app is killed/terminated in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to launch/execute app from certain background events even when app is killed/terminated in flutter.

For an example in alarm app when alarm is triggered we launch app or show alarm screen. in my case i want to launch app(also play audio) when FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessaging is called without any user actions.

examples will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you find any solution??

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can launch your app when the alarm is fired.
Use the `android_alarm_manager_plus` plugin with this [hack](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30555#issuecomment-501597824).

The `AlarmBroadcastReceiver.onRecieve()` function will be run when the alarm is fired, and then your app will be launched.

And launching the app in the background is needed permissions so reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65486556/14434806).