# How can I get a Xamarin forms app to auto start on Android 10?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-10.0

I have put in place the following:

I added `<receiver android:name="BootReceiver"></receiver>` to application in the manifest XML file.

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` to the manifest also.

I created a new class in the droid project called BootReceiver:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using uarapp.droid;

[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, DirectBootAware = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        context.StartActivity(i);
    }
}
```

The app does not start when the device boots. From Googling it looks like this process has changed for latest version of Android. Anybody know what needs to change? I can't find it online anywhere.

In case it matters the specific device I'm targetting is a RealWear HMT-1.

Comment: I test your code at Android 6.0, app can auto start, but Android 10 can not auto start, as FreakyAli said that you can show a service notification at specific time.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed with Android 10 there are a lot of restrictions on starting something in the background more information [here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

The possible solution is in the following answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421118/7462031

Possible Solutions:

> 1- You can choose just show a service notification, and start pending intent with a click
> 2- You can use full-screen intents to show your intent immediately as shown in the other answer and suggested by Google.
> For full-screen intent solution, as described in the official document
> The system UI may choose to display a heads-up notification, instead of launching this intent, while the user is using the device.
> 3- To start the activity automatically in the background, The most possible solution in my view is adding "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" to the manifest file. And ask for user permission once when the app opened the first time. (The user can give this permission manually - (Settings-Apps-Your App-Advanced- Draw over other apps))

I have also read about some brands restricting the above solutions so you might wanna investigate that too.

Good luck feel free to get back if you have queries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll check them out. This does not need to run in the background. It's a full screen app that will be the only app this device uses. We want to remove as many steps to getting into the app as possible.

Comment: Looking at the list here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts the first exception would seem to apply but in practise the app doesn't start. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: It does apply in this case

Comment: I see. So there is some other issue preventing the app from starting I guess...

Comment: My guess is it could be a brand restriction could you confirm the same?