# Losing notification data after reboot

Tags: android, database, notifications, reboot

I am building a note app, that uses alarm manager to set multiple notifications, but when a reboot the phone, the notification is not showing up.

I tried to save notifications in a db, but is not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Alarms do not persist through a reboot. You need to set them again at boot up. Is that your problem? It's not quite clear what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/5505680) is how you start your app after reboot automatically.
After restart, check your db and re-post the notifications, what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a receiver that launches a Service after a reboot.

In your manifest register for Boot Complete

...
    
     
     
     
     
      ...

In your boot receiver, launch a service.

```
public class MyRebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MeCorpServiceClass.class);
      serviceIntent.putExtra("caller", "RebootReceiver");
      context.startService(serviceIntent);
   }
```

}

Here is an example for a service class to run in the background.

```
   public class MeCorpServiceClass extends IntentService{

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
         String intentType = intent.getExtras().getString("caller");
         if(intentType == null) return;
         if(intentType.Equals("RebootReceiver"))
              //Do reboot stuff
         //handle other types of callers, like a notification.
     }
 }
```

OR Just use a third party like Urban AirShip, which handles all that for you.