# Auto Restart App on Reboot not working on Rooted Android 6 Device

Tags: android, reboot, autostart

I am working on auto launch app after restart device (Rooted android 6). 
I followed approaches from this link [How do I start my app on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-do-i-start-my-app-on-startup)

Its working fine on normal devices and emulator but not working on rooted device.

Can you pls help on this. Thank you.