# Flutter App Start When System is Turned On

Tags: flutter

Is there anyway to make an app start when system is turned on? Have tried [autostart](https://pub.dev/packages/autostart) and [android_autostart](https://pub.dev/packages/android_autostart) package, but its still not working. Tried using template code from the package but it do nothing at all.

```
 ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: () async => await AndroidAutostart.navigateAutoStartSetting,
       child: Text("Navigate AutoStart Setting"),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't
This autostart feature is available:
`navigateAutoStartSetting Supported Manufactures: - Xiaomi - Oppo - Vivo - Letv - Honor`

https://pub.dev/packages/android_autostart

Comment: Ah I see, so its not for every vendor. Any idea how to use give autostart function in stock android?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-do-i-start-my-app-on-startup