# How to start your Android app at boot in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to start my app automatically at **boot** on Android devices.

Is there any package or any solution for doing this? I know how to do it in native Android code, but how can it be done in Flutter?

Comment: You can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392009/13109852

Comment: exactly but how to do that in flutter

Comment: Actually you can do it exactly as in the answer. You just have to change "com.myapp.MyService" to your own. Finally, you should update the name "MyService.class" to "MyActivity.class".

Comment: 'onReceive' hides member of supertype 'BroadcastReceiver' and needs 'override' modifier. getting this error

Comment: You should add @Override annotation top of onReceive method, if you already added you could add more code in your post.

Comment: yeah that error is gone now ....the app runs fine... but i dont know why but it is not working

Comment: Check my answer below, maybe an issue with `autostart` restrictions

Answer (score 5):

Create a new java class in your `android/src/main/java/<package-name>/..` folder (same folder as MainActivity.java)

Call it whatever you want e.g. BootBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package <your package name here>;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

add this android permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

add this at the bottom of the `<application ... />` object inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver" >   
    <intent-filter>   
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> 
    </intent-filter>   
</receiver>
```

The name of the `<receiver .. />` should match the name of the class. Just copy above.

I've found certain devices, such as Xiaomi, have a security feature to prevent "autostart". This can be enabled/disabled for an app in the Security app, or search for "autostart" in the Settings and you'll be taking to the correct section.

I think the app needs to opened at least once before this will work.

Comment: If i want start socket, how this code work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You should be able to see in the `BootBroadcastReceiver` that inside of `onReceive` it starts a new `Intent`. In this case it starts `MainActivity.class`, which will essentially begin running the app in the background. In summary, when the device is booted (turned on), and it has finished initialising whatever it needs to do, it will then send a message to all BootBroadcastReceivers that the device has finished turning on.

Comment: Can you help me auto start socket on backround? I'm was try one more package foreground and backround service, but notification always show

Comment: not contains this folder in news apps in Flutter, using kotlin for default now...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `auto_start_flutter` package.

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_start_flutter

Comment: Thanks I tried it. Looks like  Samsung A03 does not support the package auto_start_flutter. Which phone did you test on?