# Android studio custom lock screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make and Android Studio Kotlin app that acts as a custom lock screen. The problem I have is, I can't get the app to show up every time I turn on the device. I've gotten to the point where I can open the app, turn off the device, and when I turn it on the app shows up. I need some sort of service or background task that is always running, that shows the app on the lock screen. I am new to Android Studio, so I'm not exactly sure on how to do this...

here's the code I have so far:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.WindowManager

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        window.addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY
        )
    }
}
```

And in my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Any advice or code on how I should approach this?
Also, I am aware of the other posts on stack overflow about this, but those are all ~10 years old, and don't seem to be working for me.

Comment: I found this answer, maybe it helps you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-do-i-start-my-app-when-the-phone-starts-on-android

Comment: @RafaelMoreira That was updated recently, but is 12 years old.